# Javascript Reduce or Flatten an object?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an object of data that I am working with that is dynamic and comes from a database call. If the record contains `approval` details, it will be contained in the object I get back, otherwise it will be omitted.

My problem is that I have an export method that is taking the object and turning it into an excel file, but this is only using the first level of the object, thus missing possible approval data.

I am trying to figure out how to flatten or reduce an object so that it brings all of the key/values to the parent level.

**Example Code:**

```
// Current Data
var obj = [{
    "toolSuite": "Enterprise Product",
    "toolStatus": "Active",
    "toolOwnerGroup": "PD",
    "toolTier": "1",
    "infoSec": "Yes",
    "sso": "?",
    "toolPortfolio": "Enterprise Product",
    "NeedByDate": "29-Jun-2018",
    "approvals": {
        "approval": { <--- Need to move all this data to the parent level
            "ApprovalID": "139",
            "TaskID": "232",
            "SubmissionDate": "2018-10-03T22:19:24.153",
            "WhoSubmitted": "Q1234",
            "Approver": "Q5678",
            "IsCanceled": "0",
            "ApproverFirst": "Bob",
            "ApproverLast": "Builder",
            "ApproverNTID": "bbuilder"
        }
    }
}, {
    "toolSuite": "Enterprise Product",
    "toolStatus": "Active",
    "toolOwnerGroup": "PD",
    "toolTier": "1",
    "infoSec": "Yes",
    "sso": "?",
    "toolPortfolio": "Enterprise Product",
    "NeedByDate": "29-Jun-2018",
    "ApprovalID": "139"
}]


// Desired Output
var obj = [{
    "toolSuite": "Enterprise Product",
    "toolStatus": "Active",
    "toolOwnerGroup": "PD",
    "toolTier": "1",
    "infoSec": "Yes",
    "sso": "?",
    "toolPortfolio": "Enterprise Product",
    "NeedByDate": "29-Jun-2018",
    "ApprovalID": "139",
    "TaskID": "232",
    "SubmissionDate": "2018-10-03T22:19:24.153",
    "WhoSubmitted": "Q1234",
    "Approver": "Q5678",
    "IsCanceled": "0",
    "ApproverFirst": "Bob",
    "ApproverLast": "Builder",
    "ApproverNTID": "bbuilder"

}, {
    "toolSuite": "Enterprise Product",
    "toolStatus": "Active",
    "toolOwnerGroup": "PD",
    "toolTier": "1",
    "infoSec": "Yes",
    "sso": "?",
    "toolPortfolio": "Enterprise Product",
    "NeedByDate": "29-Jun-2018",
}]
```

In the code above, the first object has the `approvals.approval` data. I am trying to bring this data to the parent level. It is not an array of data so there won't be duplicate keys.

I am currently using `lodash` in my project for other items but I wasn't able to find anything I could easily run this through to do what I need.

For this situation, is it something I need to `reduce` or `flatten`? It *should* only ever be `approvals.approval` but if there is a way I can just specify a depth of say `3` and it can move this data to the parent, it would be ideal.

What approach should I be taking this with type of object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a library, just spread or `Object.assign` the `approval` object into the parent object, and then delete the `approvals` key:

```js
var obj=[{"toolSuite":"Enterprise Product","toolStatus":"Active","toolOwnerGroup":"PD","toolTier":"1","infoSec":"Yes","sso":"?","toolPortfolio":"Enterprise Product","NeedByDate":"29-Jun-2018","approvals":{"approval":{"ApprovalID":"139","TaskID":"232","SubmissionDate":"2018-10-03T22:19:24.153","WhoSubmitted":"Q1234","Approver":"Q5678","IsCanceled":"0","ApproverFirst":"Bob","ApproverLast":"Builder","ApproverNTID":"bbuilder"}}},{"toolSuite":"Enterprise Product","toolStatus":"Active","toolOwnerGroup":"PD","toolTier":"1","infoSec":"Yes","sso":"?","toolPortfolio":"Enterprise Product","NeedByDate":"29-Jun-2018","ApprovalID":"139"}];

Object.assign(obj[0], obj[0].approvals.approval);
delete obj[0].approvals;
console.log(obj[0]);
```

If multiple items in the `obj` array have `approvals: { approval: { ... } }` properties that need to be transferred, then use a loop:

```
obj.forEach((object) => {
  const { approvals } = object;
  if (!approvals) return;
  Object.assign(object, approvals.approval);
  delete object.approvals;
});
```

I'd also recommend renaming your `obj` array to something else, if possible - it's an array, not a plain object, so perhaps call it something like `arr` to avoid confusion.

Comment: `Object.assign` has better support than object spread, and also doesn't reassign the object (not sure if that'd actually be a problem here, but I did it anyway)

Comment: Since this object will be of some unknown size, will this work the same way within some type of loop/iteration ?

Comment: @SBB What do you mean, "of some unknown size"? Do you mean there may be multiple items in the `obj` array which have an `approvals: { approval: { ...props } }` object that needs to be transferred?

Comment: The data is an array of objects. There could be 20 objects in this array and only a few of them could have the `approvals.approval` level. Just trying to figure out how to have this apply to the whole object without specifying at a specific index like your example

Comment: @SBB If that's a "yes", then see edit, just loop over the items in the array

Comment: spread is faster that Object.assign on supporting browsers. the only modern browser that doesn't support is edge

Answer (score 0):

Using `lodash` this is somewhat more readable (via [mergeWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#mergeWith) and [omit](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#omit)) like this:

```js
var data = { "toolSuite": "Enterprise Product", "toolStatus": "Active", "toolOwnerGroup": "PD", "toolTier": "1", "infoSec": "Yes", "sso": "?", "toolPortfolio": "Enterprise Product", "NeedByDate": "29-Jun-2018", "approvals": { "approval": { "ApprovalID": "139", "TaskID": "232", "SubmissionDate": "2018-10-03T22:19:24.153", "WhoSubmitted": "Q1234", "Approver": "Q5678", "IsCanceled": "0", "ApproverFirst": "Bob", "ApproverLast": "Builder", "ApproverNTID": "bbuilder" } } }

const result = _(data)
  .mergeWith(data.approvals.approval)
  .omit('approvals')
  .value()  

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

In the case of having the `data` being an array you can simply [map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#map) through since you do expect to get the same number of outputs as inputs:

```js
var data = [{ "toolSuite": "Enterprise Product", "toolStatus": "Active", "toolOwnerGroup": "PD", "toolTier": "1", "infoSec": "Yes", "sso": "?", "toolPortfolio": "Enterprise Product", "NeedByDate": "29-Jun-2018", "approvals": { "approval": { "ApprovalID": "139", "TaskID": "232", "SubmissionDate": "2018-10-03T22:19:24.153", "WhoSubmitted": "Q1234", "Approver": "Q5678", "IsCanceled": "0", "ApproverFirst": "Bob", "ApproverLast": "Builder", "ApproverNTID": "bbuilder" } } }, { "toolSuite": "Enterprise Product", "toolStatus": "Active", "toolOwnerGroup": "PD", "toolTier": "1", "infoSec": "Yes", "sso": "?", "toolPortfolio": "Enterprise Product", "NeedByDate": "29-Jun-2018" }]

const result = _.map(data, obj => _(obj)
   .mergeWith(_.get(obj,'approvals.approval'))
   .omit('approvals')
   .value())

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```